# Asynchronous function working as synchronous call

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

Below is the code I am using. Intended to make it an asynchronous call to time consuming function.

```
async Task<DataSet> GetDataAsync()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SqlDataAdapter adpator = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1;select * from table2;select * from table3;select * from table4"
            , @"Data Source=ANKIT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IM_DB;Integrated Security=True");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adpator.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }

    protected async void btnFillData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Going to run a blocking thread....";
        Task<DataSet> dsAsync = GetDataAsync();
        lblStatus.Text = "Going to await the same......";
        DataSet ds = await dsAsync;
        lblStatus.Text = "released from await";
        gvIngredient.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gvIngredient.DataBind();
    }
```

Function **GetDataAsync** working as a synchronous call. I want it to be asynchronous as it is having a database call to fetch thousands of records which is time consuming.

There is something that I missed in the async model on asp.net.

Comment: What error your are getting?

Comment: To make the `GetDataAsync` working as asynch, your calls to db `must be asynch`, otherwise, the calls are blocking

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

**The first problem:**

The modifier `async` doesn't make your method asynchronous, it just gives you an opportunity to use the `await` keyword inside. Thus, the function `GetDataAsync` is not asynchronous - it uses the same thread which it has been called. To make this function asynchronous you have to use the `Task` class and the `StartNew` method like this:

```
Task<DataSet> GetDataAsync()
{
    Function<DataSet> func = () =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SqlDataAdapter adpator = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1;select * from table2;select * from table3;select * from table4"
               , @"Data Source=ANKIT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IM_DB;Integrated Security=True");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adpator.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    };

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(func);
}
```

Check [this](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2014/10/09/behind-net-4-5-async-scene-performance-impact-asynchronous-programming-c/) really useful article up to understand how `async\await` works.

**The second:**

Your code keeps the `SqlDataAdapter` in the memory after each call of the `GetDataAsync`. This behavior leads to the memory leaks. You'd better use the `using` statement:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
    adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Function GetDataAsync working as a synchronous call.

Yes. In fact, there is a compiler warning that will tell you `GetDataAsync` will run synchronously.

It is possible to make it asynchronous, but not using the `DataSet.Fill` approach. That is a Very Old way of doing things, and was not updated to use the new asynchronous APIs. You'd have to use something like Entity Framework 6 or asynchronous DbCommands.

But before you head down that path...

```
protected async void btnFillData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblStatus.Text = "Going to run a blocking thread....";
  Task<DataSet> dsAsync = GetDataAsync();
  lblStatus.Text = "Going to await the same......";
  DataSet ds = await dsAsync;
  lblStatus.Text = "released from await";
  gvIngredient.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
  gvIngredient.DataBind();
}
```

This code shows a misunderstanding of how ASP.NET works. When the button is clicked, there is a single HTTP request sent to the ASP.NET server, and the server can only send a single HTTP response. This response is only sent at the *end* of the click event method. So, setting `lblStatus.Text` multiple times won't have any effect - only the last update will be seen by the user.

Put another way, `await` on ASP.NET only yields to the ASP.NET runtime; it does not yield to the client (browser). The HTTP response is not sent until all `await`s have completed.

So, what you're *really* asking is how to *start* a long-running operation in ASP.NET and then have the client update *later* with progress or completion information. For this you'll need a different technology, such as SignalR, AJAX, or `UpdatePanel`.